# Transitive constituents of a group - Definition

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, definition

How are the transitive constituents of a group defined?
So far I have only found the definition that "the transitive constituents of a group G are the constituents of G on the orbits of G on $\Omega$".
However, this definition rather confuses me since it makes use of a previously unmentioned set $\Omega$ and implies yet another definition of constituents.

Also I have found a note claiming that a book by Wielandt explains it in more detail. Does anybody know what the title of the book is?

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Wielandt's book, the definition is for a permutation group $G$ on a set $\Omega$, which means that $G$ is a subgroup of ${\rm Sym}(\Omega)$. The transitive constituents are more often referred to as the orbits these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, transitive constituents are not defined for abstract groups, but for a group acting on a set. (Similarly for the notion of transitive group itself.)

A transitive constituent is the permutation group induced by the action of the group on one of its orbits.

More formally, if $G$ is a group acting on a set and $\Delta$ is one of its orbits, then there is a natural homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathrm{Sym}(\Delta)$. The transitive constituent is the image of this homomorphism.

(A good exercise to test your understanding is to compute the kernel of the homomorphism.)

As an aside, I think this terminology is somewhat outdated and don't remember seeing it in any paper more recent than the 70s or 80s or so.